# in flutterflow google login is work in only run mode, but when i take it on other device it is not working?

Tags: flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-signin, flutterflow

I have tried SHA1 key and SHA256 key in my firebase account, but there is no result.

I want to apply google login in every user which is created on my app.

I have tried all the things but still its same. If anyone who are working on FlutterFlow can help me.

Thanks in advance.